# Google Analytics not initialising in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, ios8, xcode6

My new swift app does not initialise Google Analytics for some reason. I created a bridging header in my project for all the GAnalytics files:

```
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceFields.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceProduct.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceProductAction.h"
#import "GAIEcommercePromotion.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
#import "GAILogger.h"
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"
#import "GAITracker.h"
```

And this is part of my AppDelegate.swift file:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("allowganalytics") {
        GAI.sharedInstance().trackUncaughtExceptions = true
        GAI.sharedInstance().dispatchInterval = 10
        var tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().trackerWithTrackingId("UA-******-1")
        tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("ui_action", action: "app_launched",label:"launch",value:nil).build())
    }
    return true
}
```

If I check the system log of the device, I doesn't say anything occurring to Google Analytics.

Comment: Where do you set the NSUserDefaults for key "allowganalytics"?

Comment: In the Settings bundle. But same result if I comment that out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do like this.

```
     GAI.sharedInstance().trackerWithTrackingId("UA-*******-1")
                GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker..allowIDFACollection = true
GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("ui_action", action: "app_launched",label:"launch",value:nil).build())
```

Comment: This does not work see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591930/google-analytics-not-working-with-swift-1-2-and-xcode-6-3