# Google Analytics not working with Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, google-analytics, xcode6

I tried to use [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3) with my Swift 1.2 app using Xcode 6.3beta.

My bridging header works fine and contains:

```
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceFields.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceProduct.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceProductAction.h"
#import "GAIEcommercePromotion.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
#import "GAILogger.h"
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"
#import "GAITracker.h"
```

I tried the following Swift code to track a page:

```
  var tracker2:GAITracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker as GAITracker
  tracker2.set(kGAIScreenName, value:"Home Screen")
  tracker2.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build())
```

But the last line above raises the following error:

```
Cannot invoke 'send' with an argument list of type '(NSMutableDictionary!)'
```

I found similar questions like: [Google Analytics not initialising in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380638/google-analytics-not-initialising-in-swift), [Using Google Analytics with Swift on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799535/using-google-analytics-with-swift-on-ios)

**What do I have to change to make the code above working with Swift 1.2?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same problem. Here is how I got it to work

```
let build = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createAppView().set(screenName, forKey: kGAIScreenName).build() as NSDictionary
tracker.send(build as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

Comment: `as [NSObject : AnyObject]` is enough