# UIButton Event Tracking Google Analytics (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, uibutton

I would like to track an event when the user taps a UIButton with Google Analytics. I have the code below but I am shown an error. Where am I going wrong? Thanks

Code:

```
@IBAction func startGame1(sender: AnyObject) {

        var tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker

        tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("Game 1", action: "Start Pressed", label: "Start Timer One", value: nil).build()) 
    }
```

Error:

```
Cannot invoke 'send' with an argument list of type'(NSMutableDictionarry)'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Analytics not working with Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591930/google-analytics-not-working-with-swift-1-2-and-xcode-6-3)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since Swift 1.2 is released, you have to cast `GAIDictionaryBuilder` as `[NSObject : AnyObject]`

See this post on StackOverflow

[Google Analytics not working with Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591930/google-analytics-not-working-with-swift-1-2-and-xcode-6-3)

There is the solution for your issue

```
@IBAction func startGame1(sender: AnyObject) {

        var tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker

        tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("Game 1", action: "Start Pressed", label: "Start Timer One", value: nil).build() as [NSObject : AnyObject]) 
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey jre, it dosent help in Swift 2.0 , error : NSMutableDictionary is not convertible to [NSObject : AnyObject]   
 . suggestion?

Answer (score 16):

For Swift 5.

1.You should add GoogleService-Info.plist file in your project (see Google docs).

2.You should add this property in your Info.plist file:

```
<key>GoogleAnalytics</key>
<dict>
    <key>TRACKING_ID</key>
    <string>"put_your_tracking_id_here"</string>
</dict>
```

3.In AppDelegate class, in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
// GAI
    if let gai = GAI.sharedInstance(),
        let gaConfigValues = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["GoogleAnalytics"] as? [String: String],
        let trackingId = gaConfigValues["TRACKING_ID"]
    {
        gai.logger.logLevel = .error
        gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = false
        gai.tracker(withTrackingId: trackingId)
    } else {
        assertionFailure("Google Analytics not configured correctly")
    }
```

4.In your ViewController, in the viewDidLoad metod (for example):

```
// GAI
    let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
    tracker?.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "Your_mark_name")
    let eventTracker: NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build()
    tracker?.send(eventTracker as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

5.After what you should drink your beer ;)

---

For Swift 3

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
tracker.set(kGAIDescription, value: "ScreenViewName")
let eventTracker: NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build()
tracker.send(eventTracker as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

OR...

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
let eventTracker: NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEvent( 
            withCategory: "SomeCategory",
            action: "SomeAction",
            label: "SomeLabel",
            value: nil).build()
tracker.send(eventTracker as [NSObject : AnyObject]!)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks ... Google's documentation hasn't been fully updated for Swift yet ... also, it's really tough that following their iOS SDK tutorial doesn't work :(

Comment: @ChrisAllinson my pleasure )

Comment: Any sample project available ?? I'm finding hard time to implement this. When ever I run the code, I receive Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status -1 error.

Comment: @DayaKevin I have updated my post today. Hope it will help you

Answer (score 14):

Swift 3: You should use "[AnyHashable: Any]" instead of [NSObject: AnyObject].

Source: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=39

```
guard let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker else {return}
let eventTracker: NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEvent(
    withCategory: YOUR_CATEGORY_NAME,
    action: YOUR_ACTION_NAME,
    label: YOUR_LABEL_NAME,
    value: nil).build()
tracker.send(eventTracker as! [AnyHashable: Any])
```